# Converting llvm .bc file to human readable .ll file

Tags: c, linux, llvm, clang, x86-64

How can I generate human readable llvm bitcode (extension .ll) from the binary llvm bitcode (extension .bc) file?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is a useful link with all the [llvm commands](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/index.html). Obviously `llvm-dis` does what you ask.